# Data truncated for column 'cur_url' at row 1

Tags: python, django

Using django-socialregistration, got error messages:

```
Data truncated for column 'cur_url' at row 1
```

What went wrong here?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have tried to insert a larger value than field accepts, so it was literally "cut to fit".